# Where does IIS look for files

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

Can anyone explain, please, exactly how .net works. I create a web site in Visual Studio and publish it to a local server to a folder at

```
D:\WebSites\Project1
```

I create a web site in IIS and provide the address of the folder containing the files for the web site. When I publish the site, using 'fixed naming and single page assemblies', all the .aspx files go in the folder on the D drive and a dll for each page goes in the bin folder inside that folder.

I would assume that when someone wants to view a page in their browser, IIS retrieves the file(s) required from the folder specified, they get processed and turned into html and sent to the browser.

Recently when someone clicked a button on a page that calls a web service - a file not found error was reported. Apparently

```
C:\Temp\bx5tn2js.dll
```

could not be found. The thing is - why did IIS decide to look in C:\Temp for a file?

And, in the error message was a load of references to xml serialization. What is being serialized?

Comment: This is look like the temporary files that asp.net generate on compile

Comment: I don't understand. Surely the files are already compiled when I publish them. Why is anything being compiled?

Comment: Did you have see that the asp.net page have code that runs ? So its need to be compile, and there is a temporary folder for that ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178466(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Why is there a temporary folder for compiled code? All the dlls are in the bin folder within the folder that the site is published to. Why is a temporary folder needed?

Comment: I am asking myself why a temporary folder is needed? All the dlls are in the bin folder of the site - why is a temporary folder needed?

Comment: if you can not answer that to yourself, then this is a flag that you have many more to learn, and you better start buying some books about programming. (and/or read the links I give you before)

Comment: Asp.net website project and asp.net web application project do compile file differently

Answer (score 0):

This file looks like the compile files [that asp.net generates on compile.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178466(v=vs.100).aspx)

This folder can be setup on web.config on [`compilation` session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s10awwz0(v=vs.100).aspx) with the

```
tempDirectory="C:\Temp"
```

If you do not have set this option asp.net is use a default folder that is usually inside the asp.net directory, inside the windows folder. But if you have set this, and this folder did not have the correct permissions, then asp.net fails to compile the project, and you can get a message like that.

Comment: I still don't understand this. Surely the code is compiled into dlls in the bin folder within the folder the site is published to ... but you ar saying the compiled code ends up inside the asp.net directory?